# How to resolve - Unbound class path container : 'Default System Library' error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, buildpath

I have eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64 installed on my machine and jre 8 installed. When I open eclipse and import my project I get Unbound classpath container : 'Default System Library' error in Eclipse. I went to java build path and tried doing the following steps -

right click on project >> Build Path >> Configure build path >> Add Library >> JRE System Library >> Clicked Next.

Now the page shows Workspace default JRE(Unbound) instead of JRE8.And even on clicking Installed JREs no JRE is present. Tried adding JRE path(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\bin) but it says  Target is not a JDK Root. Java executable was not found.

Comment: Use `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241` directly, and please stop using Neon.3--it's 4 years old and multiple releases behind what's current.

Comment: I used C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241 directly as well but it shows " Enter the home directory of the JRE." . Also tried searching for JRE in Program Files folder from Installed JREs page but it shows no JRE installed. Not sure what is happening.